# Combining Two Access Queries With Different Amount Of Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two queries. One has 40 results the other has 37. All of the 37 are in both queries but the last three are only in one. I have a table that has all 40 items in it as well. How can I combine the two queries so that the last three show null values or zeros for the fields from the 40 item query.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` from the query with 40 results to the query with 37 results.

Comment: It sounds like you want to UNION the result sets. Do you have permission to edit the query(s)?

Comment: Of these two (union and left join), the left join is the way to go, given the overlap of the 37 records out of 40.